# Initializing "Default" final attributes in Java abstract class

Tags: java, oop, attributes, abstract-class, final

I have an abstract class which is supposed to have an (int) attribute that can't be modified after initialization and is pre-set to 1; what is the best way to do it? 
Should I make it final? 
The requirement is that inside the class I will have one and only one constructor(with parameters), and no setters.
If so, how do I make it 1 by default if it's final and (I suppose) I'm going to initialize it in the constructor?
Thanks!

Comment: if the value is always 1 then constructor has nothing to do with that. Moreover you should use `static final int var = 1` and use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact your can even hard code it, if it will always be a constant value.

For example if your variable should **always** be 25 you can do something like this:

```
public abstract class Test
{
  protected final int pressure = 25;

  //Constructor
  public Test()
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }
}
```

But if you evaluate the value on runtime you need to set it with in the constructor of the Object:

```
public abstract class Test
{
  protected final int pressure;

  //Constructor
  public Test(int pressure)
  {
    this.pressure = pressure;
  }
}
```

Note that in this case the variable **must not** be assigned earlier!

The question, if a final variable should be used depends on it's purpose. A final variable can only be assigned once over it's entire lifetime. If you have to modify it in any kind you should not use it.

Comment: @DianaI If the value should always be 1 there is no need to use the constructor to initialize it. I would suggest the first way of my answer in that case (because of readability and clean code). If you really **have** to assign it in the costructor due to the assignment use the 2nd way but without a new parameter in the constructor: `public Test(){ this.pressure = 1; }`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a constructor with parameters to set your initial values. Then, as you say, don't create any setter, and be sure your fields are private, so that no one can access it.

This way, you will do what you want, having fields initialized but never change after that.

Comment: Final cannot be changed after they are set but they can be set for the first time in the constructor :) If you know the value though you don't need to set it in the constructor. You can just write int a=1;

Comment: Yes they are private, so are you saying it's safe to not make it final as long as I have no setters, it's private and only initializable through the constructor?

Comment: Yes it is what I'm saying, but you can use final fields too. That depends on what you prefer, I think the two solutions are pretty much the same. Final is maybe a more secure option, even if my version seems safe to me. In your particular case, if you want a default value and then initialize it, `final` can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use constructor overloading to achive this. See the example:

```
public abstract class TestClass{

  private final int otherParam;
  private final int fixedParam;

  public TestClass(final int otherParam){
    this.otherParam = otherParam;
    this.fixedParam = 1;
  }

  public TestClass(final int otherParam, final int fixedParam){
    this.otherParam = otherParam;
    this.fixedParam = fixedParam;
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but I am required to only have one constructor in my class

Comment: If you are required to have only one constructor you could use Apaches ObjectUitls.defaultIfNull to check whether the provided value is null and then use your default value